# Jenkins: can we do 'continuous integration' if we have code in two different GitLab repository?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, gitlab

For Example in my case: I have two repositories on GitLab.

1- Repository A: which contains the project code in ROR.

2- Repository B: which contains the selenium-java code(web automation).

I want to apply continuous integration. Meaning, my test cases should execute which are in Repository B, if Repository A is updated.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is pretty common as downstream jobs do get executed when upstream build is successful

Comment: Yes, you should just workout the details and get started. This is not a problematic case. You can clone any repo in your script

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

1. Create a single (scripted) pipeline job.
2. Use the "snippet generator" to generate "checkout" groovy code for Repository A. Make sure "Include in polling?" is **checked**, and checkout to a specific sub-folder.
3. Use the "snippet generator" again to generate "checkout" groovy code for Repository B. Make sure "Include in polling?" is **not checked**, and checkout to a specific sub-folder other than the one specified in previous step.
4. Add additional step (sh/bat or other) to **build** your project.
5. Add additional step (sh/bat or other) to **build your tests**.
6. Add additional step (sh/bat or other) to **execute your tests**.
7. Bonus: you can use multiple build nodes to run steps 4 and 5 in parallel and save some time.

I'm using the above practice successfully with several SVN repositories in my production CI environment.